# Shipping method table rates with weight vs destination not working in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I have a magento installation with 3 magento websites/stores.

I have selected table rate shipping method in magento with weight vs destination in all 3 stores. It is working 1sta nd 2nd stores but not in 3rd store.

Following is the table rates excel sheet for the 3rd store.

```
Country  Region/State  Zip/Postal Code  Weight (and above)  Shipping Price
*        *             *                0                   6.5
*        *             *                1                   0
USA      *             *                0                   10
USA      *             *                1                   25
```

It always shows 0 weight shipping price, even if weight is greater than 0.

How can I fix this? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. You need to set bigger weights first. Something like :

```
Country  Region/State  Zip/Postal Code  Weight (and above)  Shipping Price
*        *             *                1                   0
USA      *             *                1                   25
*        *             *                0                   6.5
USA      *             *                0                   10
```

It's the only way to display properly tablerate prices.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue the first time I used Table Rates.

First, make sure you are saving this information as a CSV file.
Then open that CSV file in a code editor (Notepad++ is simplest in my opinion)
Somewhere within the 'View' menu in your code editor, you should see an option to Show Symbols->Show End of Line Characters.

Once you can see the End of Line characters they will be CR, LF, or CRLF (shown within the document itself) make sure that your file's End of Line characters are LF.

That ought to solve your issue. I can't see any issue with your data.

Comment: Hi nucleogenesis,  

Thanks for reply, 

i have seen it in Notepad++, it is showing the CR LF as the End of Line Characters. But error still comming.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in database `shipping_tablerate` field `website_id` use id website you are using.

Comment: This ought to be a comment but I guess you probably don't have sufficient privileges yet to comment.